# For two equal sized vectors, how to create a new vector containing the max (or min) of either vector at each index?

Tags: r

If I have the following two equal sized vectors,

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

y <- c(5,4,3,2,1)
```

I would like to compare x and y at every corresponding index and return another vector of the same size containing the maximum (or minimum) at each index, so the third vector would return

```
5 4 3 4 5
```

Comment: See `help("pmax")`

Comment: Try `?pmax`. p stands for parallel